# Bibtex not "connected" to Atom?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, atom

I am trying to create a pdf from a laTex document in Atom.
I looked for a solution for a while now, and it seems that I need to link my bibliography but I cannot understand how to do that.

I put the files:
documentWithoutMistakes.tex
and
references.bib 
in the same directory.

I copied a google scholar citation in references.bib file.

Then I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KS9GvK7cvmo) step by step, generated the file in Atom (open doc.tex) and then published the pdf. It seems that at some point the person links his bib file but it is not explained how to do it in mac, or I just do not understand it.

LaTex gave me the following error report:

> LaTeX Warning: Citation `.' undefined on input line 14.
>
> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 17--18
>
> No file documentWithoutMistakes.bbl.
>   [1{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
>   (./documentWithoutMistakes.aux)
>
> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

I am sorry if it's an annoying question and has been asked around many times, I cannot find the step that is missing since I do not know how to formulate my question. 
I am thankful in advance for any help!

Edit:
I copy my test-laTex document. As you see, I've been just following the tutorial, nothing too creative :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

\title{Demo Bibtex} \author{ Author } \date{\today}

\maketitle

Lorem Impsum. Some claim \cite[killing2013strategies].

\section{Section 2} Lorem Ipsum \\

\bibliographystyle{apacite} \bibliography{references} \end{document}
```

Comment: How often do you compile and do you run some bibligraphy tool (e.g. `bibtex`)?

Comment: I try to save at every step. I will my question with the laTex code I have been using.

Comment: *You* have to *physically* press a button with nearly every editor you could possibly use. The bibliography database is not worked on by magic. You need to call a computer program to do it. By pressing a button.

Comment: Please also have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography

Comment: Thank you @Johannes_B. I checked the link. Which button do you use on mac to do the magic?

Comment: https://github.com/thomasjo/atom-latex/issues/337 Suggests that it should work, since the editor runs `latexmk`. Please run the exact same code as in [Separate bibs by entry type](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber#Separate_Bibliographies_by_Entry_Type). What do you get compiling?

Comment: It has a lot more mistakes now!

o file documentWithoutMistakes.bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'westfahl:space' undefined on input line 5.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'aristotle:physics' undefined on input line 5.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'ctan' undefined on input line 5.

Comment: LaTeX Warning: Citation 'baez/online' undefined on input line 5.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'markey' undefined on input line 5.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'sigfridsson' undefined on input line 5.
Package biblatex Warning: Type 'online' not found on input line 7.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 7.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 8.

Comment: [1{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./documentWithoutMistakes.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                documentWithoutMistakes
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Comment: That was a listing of all the errors...